# Payment Gateway Integration Question In General

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, payment

I am currently working on a project where payment gateway integration is required, this questions is a general security questions regardless of what payment gateway provider I am using,

As far as I know most payment gateway require to pass a unique reference no and return URL parameters to payment request URL,  and then payment gateway will send back response to the return URL passed along with reference no and other parameters,
My questions is what if my user manually call the return URL with the parameters to fake the system like its a genuine response from IPG,

usually I have to check the unique reference no that came from response is matching the one i sent which is stored in session,

however my question is what if my user pass the unique reference no as well? since it is passed as hidden field and still visible in browser source prior to IPG request URL is called?

Comment: Even if they pass a random identifier directly the the return url, the 3rd party won't have any idea what it is, and assuming it's oAuth  or alike, won't match your app credentials, so any further request made to the 3rd party would likely fail.

Comment: assume my user is also a developer who have very good knowledge on the same  payment gateway integration which I am using, cannot he manually find the reference key and trigger a call to return URL , since he can find parameters from hidden input field which is being sent to IPG

Comment: Well, that depends on t he 3rd party doesn't it. If you're using youcandefinitelytrustme.com then there may well be backdoors, but using any reputable PSP and you shouldn't have that problem. Of course if you  start sharing out your keys and secrets arbitrarily, that's also a security issue, but that's not their problem.

Comment: This is exactly why payment providers like Stripe provide you with a token and then expect your server to send the token back to trigger the actual payment and receive confirmation that the payment was successful. I wouldn't use a payment provider that just used a redirect back with a reference as confirmation that a payment has been successful.